# C# search and modify in Json

Tags: c#, json

Can I search and modify certain values in a Json string without serialization and deserialization?

Comment: *JavaScript* doesn't event support this. JSON is JavaScript object *Notation*. When you get a JSON string, that *is* serialization. I'm not sure what you're looking for here.

Comment: Why don't you want to deserialize? That seems pointlessly dangerous. Did you hit a performance problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a string in C# so you could do something like replace or use regex. 
I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: Thank you for responses. I have a jsTree and I save the Json of the tree not to need to generate all the time, it's faster, but I need to open different nodes in case of different users. I think, I will generate only a subtree.